# Why is the Domain\Username showing up instead of the full name in User Profile Sync Service?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

I have the user profile sync service setup and running; with all of it's idiosyncrasies. I am however still getting the domain\username showing up instead of the person's first and last.

I've checked the mappings for the user properties and they appear fine. There are no errors, that I can detect and nothing special in the event log.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen? Are there any troubleshooting tips that I an employ?

Comment: did you figure out yet, please check my answer below.

Comment: Please **tag by feature** and not by version or product unless you are *absolutely certain* the question applies to SP 2010 only. This helps to attract more attention to your question and keep it relevant. See [How do I use tags](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264/) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Central Admin - > User Profile Service Application - > People --> Manage User Profile - > Find your user and make sure "Name" property is NOT blank. Also make sure First Name and Last Name are also there. When "Name" property is specified, SharePoint uses it.

Also note that, Name user profile property maps to "DisplayName" field of Active Directory.

Once you change/edit that field, it make take some time to appear in your Site depending upon how often it synchronizes, please do not expect it to appear immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Basically first troubleshooting step is to work out is this the sync service mucking up or SharePoint.

Is the Sync service actually putting first/last name into the Name attribute on the [users list](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/06/25/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list.aspx)?